# Fastest way to pack a list of floats into bytes in python

Tags: python, struct, python-3.x

I have a list of say 100k floats and I want to convert it into a bytes buffer.

```
buf = bytes()
for val in floatList:
   buf += struct.pack('f', val)
return buf
```

This is quite slow. How can I make it faster using only standard Python 3.x libraries.

Comment: `'f'` gets you a C *f*loat (32 bits); you no doubt want a Python float aka C *d*ouble (64 bits) so you and your followers should be using `'d'`

Comment: You're right, I was being careless with my datatypes. But I actually did want single precision floats.

Comment: Looks like this question could really benefit from a new answer which times each approach suggested in all the other answers

Comment: Don't forget the alternate approach: Instead of populating floatlist, then converting it to a bytearray, you could generate the data in the bytearray to begin with.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just tell `struct` how many `float`s you have. 100k floats takes about a 1/100th of a second on my slow laptop.

```
import random
import struct

floatlist = [random.random() for _ in range(10**5)]
buf = struct.pack('%sf' % len(floatlist), *floatlist)
```

Comment: FWIW: works with `array.array` but it is worth noting that `array.tobytes()` returns the same as `struct.pack(...)`. So one may use an `array('f`, [...])` and have `append`, indexer accessibility, etc. Array.array does not have all of the same methods as `list`, but might be easier to implement in many cases.

Comment: This is good, but it's worth noting the '`*`' operator seems inefficient, it is needlessly convting floatlist into a tuple before passing it to struct.pack. Is there a way to pack from an iterable, instead of passing all values as args? Perhaps create the buffer first and then assign to a slice of it?

Comment: I added an answer at the bottom of this page, which does the slice-assignment, and in my measurements, is faster than this answer.

Comment: @IAbstract `array.array`, unlike struct seems to be in native endian order, so it's not a replacement for struct.

Comment: For reference: 100k floats in 1/100th of a second sounds "plenty fast" in some contexts, but if you were, for example, generating opengl data on the CPU and expecting to re-render it at 60 or 250 frames per second, then this would be a significant bottleneck.

Comment: @JonathanHartley For sure. But if that's the case then you likely don't have the restriction the OP stated, "using only standard Python 3.x libraries".

Comment: @agf Often true. Some exceptions: One popular Python hobbyist gamedev library, Pyglet, has as an explicit design goal to only use Python, without needing to bundle any compiled binaries.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ctypes, and have a double-array (or float array) exactly as you'd have in C , instead of keeping your data in a list. This is fair low level, but is a recommendation if you need great performance and if your list is of a fixed size.

You can create the equivalent of a  C
`double array[100];`
in Python by doing:

```
array = (ctypes.c_double * 100)()
```

The `ctypes.c_double * 100` expression yields a Python class for an array of doubles, 100 items long. To wire it to a file, you can just use `buffer` to get its contents:

```
>>> f = open("bla.dat", "wb")
>>> f.write(buffer(array))
```

If your data is already in a Python list, packing it into a double array may or may not be faster than calling `struct`as in Agf's accepted answer - I will leave measuring which is faster as homework, but all the code you need is this:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> array = (ctypes.c_double * len(floatlist))(*floatlist)
```

To see it as a string, just do: `str(buffer(array))`  - the one drawback here is that you have to take care of float size (float vs double) and CPU dependent float type - the struct module can take care of this for you.

The big win is that with a float array you can still use the elements as numbers, by accessing then just as if it where a plain Python list, while having then readily available as a planar memory region with `buffer`.

Comment: The use of '`*floatlist`' needlessly converts floatlist to a new tuple before passing it to struct.pack. See my answer.

Comment: Where does the function `buffer()` come from?

Comment: `buffer` was a builtin function in Python 2 - some of its functionality, but not all, is replaced by  `memoryview` (also a built-in)  in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typememoryview

Answer (score 9):

A couple of answers suggest

```
import struct
buf = struct.pack(f'{len(floatlist)}f', *floatlist)
```

but the use of '`*`' needlessly converts `floatlist` to a tuple before passing it to `struct.pack`. It's faster to avoid that, by first creating an empty buffer, and then populating it using slice assignment:

```
import ctypes
buf = (ctypes.c_double * len(floatlist))()
buf[:] = floatlist
```

Other performance savings some people might be able to use:

- You can reuse an existing buffer by just doing the assignment again, without having to create a new buffer.
- You can modify parts of an existing buffer by assigning to the appropriate slice.

Comment: How would you convert it to little-endian bytes using your method?

Comment: @Robin Great question. I don't know! But it's a long time since I've thought about byte-manipulation code, so I'm definitely not an expert.

Answer (score 2):

As with strings, using `.join()` will be faster than continually concatenating. Eg:

```
import struct
b = bytes()
floatList = [5.4, 3.5, 7.3, 6.8, 4.6]
b = b.join((struct.pack('f', val) for val in floatList))
```

Results in:

```
b'\xcd\xcc\xac@\x00\x00`@\x9a\x99\xe9@\x9a\x99\xd9@33\x93@'
```

Comment: This is much better than the OP's original, but calling struct.pack() many times, instead of once as per other answers, seems to be suboptimal.

Comment: @JonathanHartley Yeah, that's fair - I kinda fixed half the problem here but left half on the plate, I'd agree other answers are better.

Answer (score 2):

That should work:

```
return struct.pack('f' * len(floatList), *floatList)
```

Comment: The '`*`' operator needlessly converts floatlist to a new tuple before passing it to struct.pack. This will be slow for large arrays. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

For array of single precision float there are two options: to use `struct` or `array`.

```
In[103]: import random
import struct
from array import array

floatlist = [random.random() for _ in range(10**5)]

In[104]: %timeit struct.pack('%sf' % len(floatlist), *floatlist)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.86 ms per loop

In[105]: %timeit array('f', floatlist).tostring()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.11 ms per loop
```

So `struct` is faster.

Comment: Also, the nice thing about 'struct', is that with one call, one can put heterogeneous types in it, for example an array of structs where each struct is three floats, three unsigned bytes, and one byte of padding. Handy for OpenGL interleaved buffers.

Comment: The use of '`*floatlist`' needlessly converts floatlist to a new tuple before passing it to struct.pack. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you really do want single-precision 'f' floats, you might like to try the [array module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/array.html) (in the the standard library since 1.x).

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> import array
>>> myarray = array.array('f')
>>> for guff in [123.45, -987.654, 1.23e-20]:
...    mylist.append(guff)
...    myarray.append(guff)
...
>>> mylist
[123.45, -987.654, 1.23e-20]
>>> myarray
array('f', [123.44999694824219, -987.6539916992188, 1.2299999609665927e-20])
>>> import struct
>>> mylistb = struct.pack(str(len(mylist)) + 'f', *mylist)
>>> myarrayb = myarray.tobytes()
>>> myarrayb == mylistb
True
>>> myarrayb
b'f\xe6\xf6B\xdb\xe9v\xc4&Wh\x1e'
```

This can save you a bag-load of memory, while still having a variable-length container with most of the list methods. The array.array approach takes 4 bytes per single-precision float. The list approach consumes a pointer to a Python float object (4 or 8 bytes) plus the size of that object; on a 32-bit CPython implementation, that is 16:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(123.456)
16
```

Total: 20 bytes per item best case for a `list`, 4 bytes per item always for an `array.array('f')`.

Comment: The use of '`*mylist`' needless converts mylist to a new tuple before passing it to struct.pack. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the slowness will be that you're repeatedly appending to a bytestring. That copies the bytestring each time. Instead, you should use `b''.join()`:

```
import struct
packed = [struct.pack('f', val) for val in floatList]
return b''.join(packed)
```

Comment: This is about six times slower than calling `struct` once for 100k `float`s.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the best way is to create a cycle:

e.g.

```
import struct 
file_i="test.txt"
fd_out= open ("test_bin_file",'wb')
b = bytes()
f_i = open(file_i, 'r')
for riga in file(file_i):
     line = riga
     print i,float(line)
     i+=1
     b=struct.pack('f',float(line))
     fd_out.write(b)
     fd_out.flush()


fd_out.close()
```

To append to an existing file use instead:

```
fd_out= open ("test_bin_file",'ab')
```

Comment: The question is asking for the fastest way. I don't believe writing to a file on disk will be fastest. I confess I have not measured it. Correct me if I'm wrong.