# Speed up struct.pack over a large list of floats

Tags: python, numpy, struct, byte

I have a dataframe containing millions of floats. I want to turn them into bytes and join them in a single line. Iterating over each of them is kinda slow. Is there a way to speed this up?

```py
import struct
import numpy as np


# list of floats [197496.84375, 177091.28125, 140972.3125, 120965.9140625, ...]
# 5M - 20M floats in total
data = df.to_numpy().flatten().tolist()

# too slow
dataline = b''.join([struct.pack('>f', event) for event in data])
```

I tried another approach, but apart from being slow, it also produces a different result

```py
import struct
import numpy as np


def myfunc(event):
    return struct.pack('>f', event)


data = df.to_numpy().flatten()

myfunc_vec = np.vectorize(myfunc)
result = myfunc_vec(data)
dataline = b''.join(result)
```

**UPD**: found an example here [Fastest way to pack a list of floats into bytes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940859/fastest-way-to-pack-a-list-of-floats-into-bytes-in-python), but it doesn't allow me to specify endianess. Putting this `'%s>f'` instead of `'%sf'` results in an error:
`error: bad char in struct format`

```
import random
import struct


floatlist = [random.random() for _ in range(10**5)]
buf = struct.pack('%sf' % len(floatlist), *floatlist)
```

Comment: I think you can use `array.tobytes` if you're using `numpy 1.9.0` or newer.

Comment: Try `buf = struct.pack('>%sf' % len(floatlist), *floatlist)`

Comment: Thanks both of you! `np.array(df.to_numpy().flatten(), dtype='>f').tobytes()` works too